# SSL Certificate working on Server Machine but not outside

Tags: ssl, iis, https, ssl-certificate

I have installed Godaddy Certificate with steps below
https://in.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-iis-8-server-4951

After adding in Binding on port 443, the website opens with https on the server machine.

When tried to access from outside machine, it shows this site cannot be reached.
It is still working with http everywhere.

Note - basic things are all done like restarting server.

Comment: Is port 443 in the server's firewall marked as open for incoming traffic?

Comment: @Robert i opened the port 443 in Inbound/Outbound Rules & it started working. But i have another application on Port 90, it is not working even after opening the port 90.

Comment: When you visit with a browser, what error is displayed on the page? Is it an insecure connection or another error? Have you tried using the ping command to your server IP or website url in the cmd of the external device? You should try to make sure you 
 can receive data from the server.

Comment: @BruceZhang It is showing "This site can’t be reached". The SSL certificate in working on Server machine.

Comment: Can you post the detail error under the "This site cannot be reached" in browser? And tell me the statuscode in Developer mode of the browser.